# How get inner property value by reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-core

I want to use the reflection to get the value from a class object. In this case, Rating is my main class which contains a property of Contribution class.

Following is the structure of my class

```
public class Rating
{
    public string personal_client_id { get; set; }
    public string risk_benefit_id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string risk_event { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public Contribution contribution { get; set; }

}

public class Contribution
{
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want the value from the **contribution** property like below.

```
var Rating = RatingObject.Where(x => x.personal_client_id == pcid).FirstOrDefault();
if (Rating  != null)
{
    Type type = Rating.GetType();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("contribution");
    var aa = propertyInfo.GetValue(Rating, null);

    //aa has the Contribution property now but i don't know how can i get the property value from 
   this object
   //Remember i dont want to do this **((Contribution)(aa)).from**

}
else
{
    return "";
}
```

Please help!

Comment: GetValue is the right method but it returns object so you will need to cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using var, you can force the type of aa to be a dynamic.

```
dynamic aa = propertyInfo.GetValue(Rating, null);
return aa.from;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you already have the `rating` object, you could define a `PropertyInfo` for the property you want to read from the `Contribuition` type and use the reference on the `rating.contribution` to read it. For sample

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Rating).GetProperty("contribution");
var contribution = propertyInfo.GetValue(rating, null) as Contribution;

if (contribution != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(contribution.from);
   Console.WriteLine(contribution.value);
}
```

Remember that `PropertyInfo.GetValue` method returns an something from `object` type, so, you have to cast it to the expected type.

Comment: typeof(Contribution).GetProperty("from");. I don't want to HardCode the property name buddy.. Like Contribution. Instead of that i want something like

 var aa = propertyInfo.GetValue(Rating, null);... I want to use the type of this aa object which will be already of Type Contribution... I hope you get that

Comment: See my updates. Not sure if I get it, but you could do a safe cast the result of `GetValue` to contribution using `as` an check if it is not null and use the object.